# How do I declare a variable ignorable?

Tags: compilation, warning

How do I avoid byte-compiler warnings `Unused lexical variable` in functions defined using macros expanding to `defun`?

E.g., macro `defun-rcirc-command` in
[`rcirc.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/net/rcirc.el)
uses the `target` variable which is not used by several invocations.

In Common Lisp I can use the
[`ignorable`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_ignore.htm)
declaration: `(declare (ignorable target))`.

Bad solutions:

- Add something like `(setq target target)` to all the users of
  `defun-rcirc-command` which do not use `target`: that requires
  modifying *many* macro invocations.
- Prefixing the ignorable variable with an underscore - `_target` - does not help because `_` means `ignore`, not `ignorable`, i.e., when it is used, I get `variable '_target' not left unused`.

Comment: Prefixing them with an underscore should do it.

Comment: @politza: _ means ignore, not ignorable

Comment: Do you want to modify the macro to solve the problem? You could probably just put a `(ignore VAR)` for every defun argument before the ,@body expansion which will probably silence the errors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way I've done that so far is to add a call of the shape

```
(ignore <var>)
```

This function call will be optimized away, but before that the compiler will still count it as a use, so the "unused" warning won't be triggered.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code, it appears that target is not intended to be a global variable but passed to the created function when it is called.  If that is the case, it is better to create it as a symbol local to the macro.  A simple example of a macro that creates a function that accepts an argument and adds 10 to it:

```
(defmacro xxx (name)  
  ""
  (let ((target (make-symbol "target")))
  `(defun ,name (,target) (+ 10 ,target))))
```

Calling

```
(xxx hamster)
```

will result in a function named hamster that accepts one argument.

Then you can call

```
(hamster 5)
```

and it will return `15`.

The trick is to create a new symbol that will act as the argument to the new function.

EDIT:

I have always seen that if you are referring to the generated symbol in the passed in body expression, you include the name in the call like:

```
(defmacro xxx (name t2 &rest body)  
  ""
  (let ((t2-arg (make-symbol "target")))
  `(defun ,name (&optional ,t2-arg) 
     (let ((,t2 (or ,t2-arg 10)))
       ,@body))))
```

Which then turns the calls into:

```
(xxx hamster target (+ target 20))
```

where

```
(hamster)
```

which returns `30` and

```
(hamster 20)
```

returns `40`.

Admittedly, this always bugs me when I write macros this way until I look at the usage in which it appears a parameter is declared and later used.

Comment: The body of the function is passed to the macro and it must be able to refer to `target`. IOW, your excellent suggestion is not applicable in this specific case.